# Using a monad for counting looping in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, monads

I am learning functional programming at the moment, and ofcourse I want to implement what I have learned whenever I can.

I am in the middle of a project where I have to send some http requests to a server, and I want to count how many of these requests returned a status_code 200.

Right now I have some stupid code setup as follows:

```py
global counter
while True:
    now_url = 127.0.0.1
    status, value = getStatus(now_url)
    counter += c
```

Where counter is a global counter, and if the getStatus gets a status_code of 200, the value will be 1 otherwise it will be 0.

So I was thinking maybe instead of using a global counter I could just pass around the state of the previous loop, and I would get rid of the stupid global counter value.

So I tried to implement the getStatus in a monadic way with the bind and return as such

```py
def bind(f, arg):
    res = f(arg[0])
    return res[0], arg[1] + res[1]

def ret(f):
    return (f, 0)
```

But this is not trivival since I am not using function composition in the getStatus function that is defined as such

```py
def getStatus(now_url):
    try:
        respones = requests.get(now_url)
        if respones.status_code == 200:
            return respones.status_code, 1
        else:
            return respones.status_code, 0

    except Exception as e:
        return e, 0
```

So the question is how to restructure my code in such a way that I can use the power of monads to count the number of status_code == 200.

Hope you can help :)

Comment: Your code looks like you're trying to turn python into haskell. Python is not haskell, and monads generally don't make python code better. All you need is a loop with an `if` statement that increments your counter. Don't overengineer it.

Comment: Monads are "infectious", because you don't have any means to unwrap their impure values. So to actually apply your `Writer` monad, all involved functions have to use `bind`/`ret`. In your case `getStatus` have to return a `Wrtier` monad as well.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Monads are a mathematical structure and hence totally language agnostic.

Comment: @bob I'm not saying you *can't* use monads in python. I'm saying you *shouldn't*.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I was referring to the _turn python into hakell_ part. monads ≠ haskell.

Comment: @Aran-Fey While you claim using monads / FP to be overengineering, I'd say not using monads / FP is underengineering. This article explains my reasoning much better than I could here with 412 characters left. 
 Feel free to skip right to "Programmers dislike academic terminology". 
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/software-engineers-artisans-sergei-winitzki/